# Cannot render youtube video in show using iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe

I have video:string that users input in a class called Video that is a youtube link.

my iframe keeps giving me the error 'no implicit conversion of nil into String'. Here's my code.

my videos/show.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
            <h3>Videos</h3>
            <ol class="video">
                <iframe width="560" height="349" src="<%= "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+@video.code %>"></iframe>
            </ol>
    </div>
</div>
```

my helpers/VideosHelper:

```
def code
    self.video.split('/').last if self.video
end
```

my VideosController:

```
def show
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This errors is raised because** `@video.code` returns nil, and Ruby tries to concat a String with Nil, giving the Error "No implicit conversion of nil into String".

**To solve this**, you can return an empty string instead of nil in your code method:

```
def code
  self.video.try(:split, '/').try(:last) || ''
end
```

This code will split the video link on '/' and return the last if exists, if not it will return an empty string.

**Something to remember:** Your methods should always return the same type of object, in every cases. If your method is supposed to return a String, don't return `nil` in any case, return an empty String and test it with `.present?`

Example:

```
# helper
def pretty_fullname(user)
  if user.nil?
    return ""
  else
    return "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}"
  end
end

# view
<h1><%= "Welcome " + pretty_fullname(@user) %></h1>
# This won't raise an error is user is nil.
```

Comment: I still receive the same error after using the new 'def code'

Comment: The code method should be implemented in the Video model or should receive a video object as parameter. Refering to `self` in a helper does not refer to the instanciated object but the context!

Comment: It worked!!! The youtube video renders. I'm getting an error in youtube saying that 'an error occured. Please try again later", but now i'm a step closer! Thanks :)

Comment: fixed that too. You're awesome, Yoshi. The cyber/real/mario world would be a sad place without you